# Huge difference between training accuracy and evaluation accuracy using Tensorflow Datasets class + Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I created a dataset from my data and this dataset is in the form of (features,labels). features' dimension is `[?,731,7]` (where the `?` should be 400), the corresponding labels' dimension is `[4,]` as shown in my dataset. Each `[731,7]` sample corresponds to a 4 elements array like `[0,1,0,0]`.

[image]

A few sample data:
[Sampledata1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp9m8.png)
[Sampledata2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thg3r.png)

After building a simple multi-layer neural network, the training process is normal as follow. But when I use the same dataset to validate (just to check if the algorithm is working or not), I actually got a huge difference.
I don't think it is right but I am not sure if this happens because I used .eval() wrong or my datasets got wrong.
[image]

My code for datasets creation:

```
filenames = glob.glob(main_dir+keywords)
# filenames = ['test.txt','test2.txt']
length = len(filenames) # num of files
length_samesat = 100 # happen to be this... I designed in propogation
batch_num = 731 # happen to be this...

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda filename: tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename).skip(3))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda string: tf.string_split([string],delimiter=', ').values)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.strings.to_number(x))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_num)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda tensor: tf.reshape(tensor,[batch_num,7]))
dataset = dataset.batch(1).repeat()
```

Then I zip my dataset with my label dataset and create NN and run

```
dataset_all = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset, datalabel))
dataset_all = dataset_all.shuffle(400)
visual_dataset(dataset_all,0,20)
# NN Model
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(731,7,))  # Returns a placeholder tensor

# A layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor.
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation='tanh')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation='tanh')(x)
# x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(450, activation='tanh')(x)
# x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(300, activation='tanh')(x)
# x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(450, activation='tanh')(x)
# x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu')(x)
# x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

# Instantiate the model given inputs and outputs.
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

# The compile step specifies the training configuration.
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001),
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

# Trains for 5 epochs
model.fit(dataset_all, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=400)
model.evaluate(dataset_all, steps=400)
```

Thanks!